# What is a term to refer something in the middle of a list just like "former" and "latter" is used in a list containing two things?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, word-usage

In a sentence, if someone says the *former*, they are talking about the first thing they listed, and says the *latter* for the last thing they listed. What would be the term to refer something in the middle of a list? Consider the following two scenarios:

> I like to eat burgers and hot dogs, although I like to eat the *former* more.
>
> I like to eat burgers, hot dogs and ribs, although I like to eat the ***_*_** more.

Comment: The words *former* and *latter* are comparatives, which means they can only be used in a list of two items. For a list of more than two, you need to use the corresponding superlatives, which were formerly *formest* and *lætest,* but are now *first* and *last*.

Comment: @PeterShor And *foremost* is still in use for place; *latest* for time. Corresponding to *foremost* is *hindmost*, and corresponding to *latest* is *earliest* or *soonest*.

Answer (score 10):

Counting from the beginning, the *second*. In a list of three things, the things are the *first*, *second*, and *third*.

It would be less common, but possible, to count back from the end. The thing at the end is the *last*. Before it is the *next to last*.

Another, even less common, way to count back from the end derives from Latin: *ultimate*, *penultimate*, *antepenultimate*. (However, when you are identifying the final stressed syllable of a Latin word, this is what you would normally use.)

Answer (score 1):

Linguistic accuracy and correctness apart, the common way of expressing this reference is with the phrases *first-mentioned*, *(ordinal)-mentioned*, and *last-mentioned*.  The suffix *-mentioned* too could be elided.

If I like burgers best,

> I like to eat burgers, hot dogs and ribs, although I like (to eat) the **first**(-mentioned) most. <sub>— (better say *most* among the three, right?)</sub>

There could be other ways of accomplishing this, though.